# Error in react-native application: Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component

Tags: javascript, react-native

this is the code I wrote in react-native application and I've added the image about the error I am getting when I run the app on android virtual device.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

const Header = () => {
    const { textStyle, viewStyle } = styles;

    return (
        <View style={viewStyle}>
        <Text style={textStyle} >Albums!</Text>;
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = {
    viewStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#F8F8F8'
    },
    textStyle: {
        fontSize:20
    }
};
export default Header;
```

The error is as follows:

> Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component.

[image]

Comment: Please post what the error is and what the desired outcome is

Comment: @JeremyLee Sir i've added the link to image to what the error is

Comment: I don't see the link.. my edit may have overwritten yours?

Comment: @JeremyLee Sir I've added the image again :)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the semicolon which is after the text closing tag.

```
return (
    <View style={viewStyle}>
    <Text style={textStyle} >Albums!</Text> "remove this semicolon ->;"
    </View>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want that `!` you can write code like this

```
return (
<View style={viewStyle}>
<Text style={textStyle} >{"Albums!"}</Text>
</View>
```

);